# Is there a word referring to the process of digesting information and coming up with your own opinion/ideas on a topic?

Tags: single-word-requests

It could be used in a sentence like 
"With such influences in the media leading people to believe everything they hear without ... "

Answer (score 3):

The word *synthesis* fits the definition in the question title quite well.

> **synthesis**
>
> 1 c. : the combining of often diverse conceptions into a coherent whole
>
> 2 a. : deductive reasoning
> b : the dialectic combination of thesis and antithesis into a higher stage of truth

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/synthesis

But that word wouldn't fit your example sentence especially well. It's too technical, scholastic, or extravagant for what is a very common activity (or what *should be* very common).

*Thinking*, as suggested in a comment is a reasonable choice. I'd prefer *critical thinking*, which doesn't have a substantially different meaning, but is used frequently in this context.

Another similar choice that fits the example sentence better than the definition in your title is *reflection*

> **reflection**
>
> 6 : a thought, idea, or opinion formed or a remark made as a result of meditation
>
> 7 : consideration of some subject matter, idea, or purpose

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reflection

Answer (score 1):

How about **[ponder](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ponder)**?

To ponder is:

1) *to weigh in the mind: Appraise*  or

2) *to think about: reflect on*

That would fit with your sample sentence.

Then there is **[deliberate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deliberate)**, which means:

*to think about and discuss issues or situations carefully*

This would be a less likely fit. But another good one just came to mind:

**[evaluate](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/evaluate)**

which can mean:

*to form a critical opinion of*

You could fill in your sentence by saying: *"With such influences in the media leading people to believe everything they hear without **evaluating the information** "...*

Comment: https://youtu.be/j1nKwJxaJdk

Answer (score 0):

How about **processing**? From M-W:

> **[process](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/processing)**: to subject to examination or analysis

Your example:

> "With such influences in the media leading people to believe everything they hear without **processing**, ..."